# Why is this sequence exact?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Let $X$ be a smooth complex projective curve. Let $D$ be any divisor and let $p$ be a point. Rick Miranda claims this sequence is exact on page 285 of his book on Riemann surfaces:

$$
0 \to \mathcal O(D-p) \to \mathcal O(D) \xrightarrow{\text{eval}_p}  \mathbb C_p \to 0
$$
where the last map is supposed to be evaluation at $p$ and $\mathbb C_p$ is the skyscraper sheaf of $\mathbb C$ at $p$.

1. Why does the last map make sense? A meromorphic function in $\mathcal O(D)$ can have a pole at $p$.
2. Perhaps one way to fix this is to realize that (Weil) divisors on a smooth curve are in fact locally principal, so we can find some neighborhood $U$ of $p$ with $D \mid_U = div(\phi)$. Then we can evaluate $f\phi$ (which is regular because its divisor is effective). But this depends on choice of $\phi$ so the map is no longer natural.

Comment: I think he's just being a little loose. If you have a section of a line bundle $L$ over an open set containing $p$ then you get an element of the fiber $L|_p$. This is isomorphic to $\mathbb C$ but not canonically so. He probably only cares about the dimensions of the cohomology groups (if this is the proof I'm thinking of) so this is mostly harmless.

Comment: (I think of this sequence as coming from the closed subscheme exact sequence for $p$, tensored with $\mathcal O(D)$.) anyway, it's a good question.

Comment: @Hoot Thanks. Right, I understand why $$ 0 \to \mathcal O(-p) \to \mathcal O \to \mathbb C_p \to 0$$ works, and if you tensor by $\mathcal O(D)$, then you almost get the above sequence, but you need to make a choice to get $\mathcal O(D) \otimes \mathbb C_p \cong \mathbb C_p$ (as you answered in this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1846148/locally-free-sheaf-tensor-skyscraper-sheaf.